# Code igniter returning 404 for a specific parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using `"<a href='".base_url() ."auth/confirmNewUser/".$username."' class='btn btn-sm'>Create&nbsp;Account</a>";` to generate a url which then maps to

```
    function confirmNewUser() {

    $newuser =$this->uri->segment(3);
```

The problem that I have now is this works for everything other than one specific text parameter (nicoe) which always returns 404 error. So basically it doesn't get to the method at all. I am at wits end. Any debugging advice would be really helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to create a route

```
$route['auth/confirmNewUser/(:any)'] = 'auth/confirmNewUser/$1';
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Another reason why it may not be working is because you have not got a htaccess suitable in your main directory

How to remove index.php

https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Make sure the filename of the controller and class name only has first letter uppercase rest lowercase.

Filename controllers/Auth.php

```
<?php

class Auth extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
  }

  public function confirmNewUser($username) {
      echo $username; // Testing

      $data['username'] = $username;

      $this->load->view('some_view', $data);
  }

}
```

Also make sure base url is set

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
```

Or if on live domian example

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';
```

Comment: same issue. The problem that I have is not that its not routing. It is routing all the other requests but returns 404 for that one specific parameter. Which is very peculiar.

Comment: @bidhan did you try with index.php in url it could be something to do with htaccess `http://localhost/yourproject/index.php/auth/confirmNewUser/someusername`

Comment: that worked. What could be the issue thought? keeping in mind that it was for one specific parameter